# React router redirection causes useEffect to trigger twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a route defined as following:

```
<Route path={`list`} element={<ListPage />}>
  <Route path={`sidePanel1`} element={<SidePanel1 />} />
  <Route path={`sidePanel2`} element={<SidePanel2 />} />
  <Route index element={<Navigate to={`sidePanel1`} replace />}/>
</Route>
```

So, when `/list` is typed it will be redirected to `/list/sidePanel1`.

in the `ListPage` component I have this:

```
const ListPage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<ListDto[]>([]);

  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {

    getList()
      .then(response => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, [location]);
  return (
    <ListTable data={data}/>
    <SidePanelStyles>
       <Outlet />
    </SidePanelStyles>
  );
};
```

So, my problem is that whenever I type `/list/` the useEffect will trigger since the location has changed, and then it will trigger for the second time when redirected to `/list/sidePanel1`.

I want it to only be triggered after I get redirected.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: `const location = useLocation().pathname.endsWith("sidePanel2") ? "panel2" : "panel1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting and rendering twice, just render `SidePanel1` component on the index route as well.

Example:

```
<Route path="list" element={<ListPage />}>
  <Route index element={<SidePanel1 />} />
  <Route path="sidePanel1" element={<SidePanel1 />} />
  <Route path="sidePanel2" element={<SidePanel2 />} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1):

One general-purpose solution to only react to the last change in a quick sequence of changes is to use a "debounce".

I.e. a delay between when the effect is triggered and when `getList` is called, so that if the effect is triggered again before the delay is finished, the pending call will be canceled.

```js
function useDebouncedEffect(delay, effect, triggerParams) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(f, delay)
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
  }, triggerParams)
}

useDebouncedEffect(300, () => {
  getList()
    .then(response => {
      setData(response.data);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, [location]);
```